# how to fetch Input given value to an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, input

i'm working on a calculator based on some Json data i want when i enter the longitude and latitude i get the Grid Code associated to that longitude and latitude.the problem is when i get the value form the input the result reurnd is 0 means the value of the input is undefined

this is how my code look like

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>


<form action="" id="my-form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Enter Lat</label>
    <input type="text" id="lat" step="any">
    <label for="">Enter Long</label>
    <input type="textr" id="long" step="any">

  </div>
  <input type="button" id="Btn" value="Calculate" >
  <h2 id="result">result</h2>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var desiredLat = document.getElementById("lat").value,
desiredLong = document.getElementById("long").value;
  const
  myData = {
   "datagrid": [
     { "GRIDCODE": 1735,"lat": 35.91511132, "long": -5.401484264 },
     { "GRIDCODE": 1805, "lat": 35.90677815, "long": -5.468149593 },
     { "GRIDCODE": 1808, "lat": 35.90677815, "long":-5.459816427 },
     { "GRIDCODE": 1784, "lat": 35.89844499, "long":-5.476482759 }
   ]
 };

  gridcode = lookupGridcodeByLatAndLong(myData.datagrid),
  headerHTML = gridcode ;
console.log(headerHTML);



function lookupGridcodeByLatAndLong(sourceArray){
  let gridcode = 0;
  
  for (let currentObject of sourceArray){
    if (currentObject.lat === desiredLat && currentObject.long === desiredLong){
      gridcode = currentObject.GRIDCODE;
    }
  }
 
  return gridcode;
}
$("#Btn" ).click(function() {
  $("#result").html(gridcode);
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? Were you able to find in which line the main issue could be?

Comment: i got the answer bro appreciate it the problem was that i called  lookupGridcodeByLatAndLong function in the first time with passing  lat and lang value, both value will return undefined because i haven't input them yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you get `zero` value is because you called your `lookupGridcodeByLatAndLong` function in the first time with passing your `lat` and `lang` value, both value will return undefined because you haven't input them yet.

You have to fill them with value, then hit the button to get the `lat` and `lang` value before you do your calculation to get the `GRIDCODE` and actually you don't need to parse your object value as parameter, because you initialized it as global parameter, so you can still use it inside your function without parse it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>


<form action="" id="my-form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Enter Lat</label>
    <input type="text" id="lat" step="any">
    <label for="">Enter Long</label>
    <input type="textr" id="long" step="any">

  </div>
  <input type="button" id="Btn" value="Calculate" >
  <h2 id="result">result</h2>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  const
  myData = {
   datagrid: [
     { "GRIDCODE": 1735,"lat": 35.91511132, "long": -5.401484264 },
     { "GRIDCODE": 1805, "lat": 35.90677815, "long": -5.468149593 },
     { "GRIDCODE": 1808, "lat": 35.90677815, "long":-5.459816427 },
     { "GRIDCODE": 1784, "lat": 35.89844499, "long":-5.476482759 }
   ]
 };



function lookupGridcodeByLatAndLong(lat, long){
  let gridcode = 0;
  
  var result = myData.datagrid.find(x => x.lat == lat && x.long == long)
  if (result) {
    gridcode = result.GRIDCODE;
  }
 
  return gridcode;
}
$("#Btn" ).click(function() {
 var lat = document.getElementById("lat").value,
 long = document.getElementById("long").value;
 var result = lookupGridcodeByLatAndLong(lat, long)
  $("#result").html(result);
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have edited my answer without parsing the object, you can try it one more time

Comment: it works on small data like he one given but the one i work with is more than 900000 line of data so it will take forever to find the value

Comment: I tried using `find` from js function, maybe u can try to implement it.. let's check if it success or not

Comment: like it should stops searching when it finds the first match

Comment: yap if you want to get array value just using **filter** instead of **find**